# double try_files directive for the same location in nginx

Tags: nginx

I discovered a nginx config snippet in serveral gists and config examples (mostly for PHP apps):

```
#site root is redirected to the app boot script
location = / {
    try_files @site @site;
}
#all other locations try other files first and go to our front controller if none of them exists
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @site;
}
```

But I just do not get it: Does the first try_files directive ever match? To me this looks like some nonsense hacking.

Please confirm or explain why not - thanks :)

Comment: It's a hack to unconditionally jump to @site. Personally, I prefer the `error_page` variant. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288537/nginx-try-files-proxy-and-named-location-with-404-fallback#20694873).

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens here:

The first location `= /` is only used when the path in the request is `/`, e.g. `http://example.com/`. The second location `/`is used for all other URLs, e.g. `http://example.com/foo` or `http://example.com/bar`.

The reason for the first location is to avoid any interference from `index`-directives that do a redirect to index.html or something similar.

Inside the first location the `try_files`-directive first looks for a file named `@site`, which does not exist and then redirects to the named location `@site`. The reason for this construct is that the redirect to the named location is purely internal, i.e. the `@site` location can not be accessed directly from the client and the `$uri` is kept unmodified during this redirect (which would not be the case for other redirects). The first parameter `@site` can be anything except a real existing file. I prefer to call it `DUMMY` for clarity.

The second location tries static files first and, if not found, then also redirects to the named location.