# Return custom nginx error from within named location

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have a configuration where I want to return a custom error from within a named location. However, instead I receive the standard nginx error page. I can get the custom error from a non-named location though.

To reproduce the issue, I created this simple docker-based setup:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:1.17.9

COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY 404.html /usr/share/nginx/html/404.html
```

default.conf:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    #recursive_error_pages on;

    location = /404.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        internal;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location / {
        # used in a more complex setup, this is just a minimal config
        # # See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20694873
        error_page 404 = @fwd;
        return 404;
    }

    location @fwd  {
       root /usr/share/nginx;
       error_page 404 /404.html;
    }
}
```

The 50x errors are not interesting here, I've adapted the config from the nginx docker image.

Uing something other than 404 to redirect to the named location does not make a difference.

404.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title>404</title></head>
  <body>
    my 404
  </body>
</html>
```

Build: `docker build -t mynginx .` and start `docker run --rm -p 8080:80 --name mynginx mynginx`.

Now pointing the browser to http://localhost:8080/index.html should return the standard welcome page, while http://localhost:8080/inexistent.html will return a internal nginx 404 page, not the custom one I configured.

Is there a way to actually make this work from within the named location?

Comment: Try: `try_files /404.html =404;`

Comment: Where do you suggest I should use this?

Comment: In the named location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While exploring the problem, I found out about `recursive_error_pages on;` -- but stupidly left it commented. Naturally it didn't help.

Un-commenting that directive fixes the issue!